# Redirecting ffmpeg result into another file

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get the size of an input video using ffmpeg, below is the code that I use, what I'm trying to do is to first store the result into a txt file and then do some parsing to get the size of the video:

```
$ ffmpeg -i TheNorth.mp4
```

The terminal says "At least one output file must be specified"
Then I tried this:

```
$ ffmpeg -i TheNorth.mp4 result.txt
```

The terminal says "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'size.txt'"

So how could I get the result and save it to the specified file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can store the output ffmpeg generates with piping:

```
ffmpeg -i TheNorth.mp4 2> result.txt
```

You need to use `2>` here, as ffmpeg writes to StdErr (and not StdOut).

Comment: Thanks so much, it works. where can I find information about the number 2 that you put there?

Answer (score 2):

## ffprobe

If you just want to get the size of the video then you can get that, and other info, directly with `ffprobe`. This will avoid redirection, temporary output files, and the additional parsing.

```
$ ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width -of csv=p=0:s=x input.mkv 
  1280x720
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for more examples.

## tee

For users who want to encode and capture the resulting console output, I recommend using `tee`. The problem with pure redirection is that important messages such as error messages, failures, and prompts can be missed.

You can avoid this by including `tee` to show the output in the console and to save it to a file:

```
ffmpeg -i input … output |& tee console.txt
```

`ffmpeg` outputs to stderr instead of the more typical stdout, so the `&` is added to the `|` pipe to deal with that. This is only for Bash 4+. If you're using something else then change `|&` to `2>&1` which redirects stderr to stdout before it is sent to the pipe.

Comment: Thanks, but what does &1 means here?

Comment: What is the &1 here?

Comment: @ib11 I expanded the answer to address `2>&1`.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat better idea is to use ffprobe

```
ffprobe -show_format -print_format json TheNorth.mp4
```

that will output JSON formated info about video. Guess it is easier to parse than raw output. To redirect output to file use just ordinary pipe `> result.txt` similar to accepted answer but without two.

Comment: So how can I know when should I use 2 before > and when I don't? Thanks

Comment: If you use > than STDOUT goes to file and if you use 2> than STDERR goes to file. Little bit of experimenting will help you to determine what you want to log. If you want both to go to file `> result.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Yeah I know 0 means STDIN, 1 means STDOUT and 2 means STDERR but I still don't understand is there a way to know in advance where will the ffmpeg result go?

Comment: Go agile, try logging 1, then 2 and see what you like more.